# Very slow performance in getting the results of QSqlQuery

Tags: sqlite, qt

I am seeing inexplicably slow behavior from a sqlite database in Qt. The query in the code below, when executed from the sqlite command line utility on the same database, completes instantaneously.

```
qDebug() << "Beginning" << QDateTime::currentDateTime ().toString(Qt::ISODate);
QSqlQuery q(QSqlDatabase::database(mFilename));
q.prepare( "select TextFormIndex.Id from TextFormIndex,MorphologicalAnalysisMembers,Allomorph on TextFormId=Id and AllomorphId=Allomorph._id where LexicalEntryId=:Id;" );
q.bindValue(":Id", id);

QSet<qlonglong> textFormIds;
if( !q.exec()  )
{
    qWarning() << "DatabaseAdapter::lexicalEntryTextForms" << q.lastError().text() << q.executedQuery();
    return textFormIds;
}

qDebug() << "Before while" << QDateTime::currentDateTime ().toString(Qt::ISODate);
int nResults = 0;
while( q.next() )
{
    qDebug() << nResults++ << QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString(Qt::ISODate);
    q.value(0).toLongLong();
}
qDebug() << "After while";
```

The debug output form this code is:

```
Beginning "2013-02-04T20:31:24" 
Before while "2013-02-04T20:31:26" 
0 "2013-02-04T20:31:26" 
1 "2013-02-04T20:31:27" 
2 "2013-02-04T20:31:41" 
3 "2013-02-04T20:31:44" 
After while
```

Somehow the third call is taking fourteen seconds.

This is a single method in a good-sized project. None of my queries have been executing slowly until this one.

```
create table if not exists TextFormIndex ( TextName text, LineNumber integer, Id integer );
create table if not exists MorphologicalAnalysisMembers ( _id integer primary key autoincrement, TextFormId integer, AllomorphId integer, AllomorphOrder integer );
create table if not exists Allomorph ( _id integer primary key autoincrement, LexicalEntryId integer, WritingSystem integer, Form text );
```

MorphologicalAnalysisMembers.AllomorphId corresponds to Allomorph._id. TextFormIndex.Id corresponds to MorphologicalAnalysisMembers.TextFormId.

MorphologicalAnalysisMembers has 4082 rows
TextFormIndex has 17710 rows
Allomorph has 1660 rows

Comment: What is the structure of the three tables? How many records does each have, and how many of those are returned?

Comment: I edited the question to add that information.

Comment: Are you using the same SQLite version on the command line and in your program?

Comment: Qt has 3.6.19. My command line version is 3.7.13.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the SQLite version used in your Qt is too old.

Update to the latest Qt, or [recompile Qt with a newer SQLite](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/sql-driver.html#qsqlite-for-sqlite-version-3-and-above).

Comment: I'm facing similar problem. Could you explain a bit more about the "SQLite version used is too old", or is that just a suggestion/guess? I have the problem with Qt 5.2.1, which presumably has pretty new SQLite too.

Comment: @hyde Use `SELECT sqlite_version();` to compare the versions used by Qt and the command-line shell.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, for future. My issue was because of a missing index, solved now.